# Can you get demoted from legendary arenas in Clash Royale (not counting the season reset)

Tags: clash-royale

In Clash Royale, I'm wondering whether I can get demoted from legendary arenas. For example, I'm in Challenger II with 4301 trophies. Then I lost a match, deducting 9 trophies. Normally in Arenas 1-12, I won't get demoted. But in the legendary arenas (arena 13), can I get denoted from arenas because I lost that match? I know that I can get demoted by the season reset, so this gets me thinking.

P.S. I would like to try it myself, but I wouldn't want to ruin my progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.  According to [this video around the 1:55 mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5o8BZjuVYyM) once you enter a new arena or leagues (4000+ trophies) you can not go back.

Here is the [official website](https://clashroyale.com/blog/release-notes/new-update-feature-enter-the-trophy-road.html) mentioning it as well:

> Introducing... Trophy Gates!
>   Trophy Gates allow you to save your Trophy progress, each time you reach a new Arena! When you pass through a Trophy Gate, you will NOT drop below that threshold. For example, when you hit 3600 Trophies and enter Spooky Town, you will not drop below 3600 Trophies again!
>
> Once you hit 4000+ Trophies, Trophy Gates do not exist. You can drop
>   Leagues but you will never drop below 4000 Trophies (Legendary Arena).

You didn't ask why, but in case anyone was wondering, it sounds like this was probably done to prevent people from intentionally dropping trophies and bullying lower arena players.

Comment: Correct. The highest trophy gate is 4000. No matter how high you get above 4000, you can always drop back to 4000 but not lower.